# Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1 won't update

Tags: java, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-luna

Updating the **Spring Tool Suite** in Eclipse Luna, I get the following error since I turned off the option to download updates for Eclipse 3.7:

```
**An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.quicksearch,3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.sts,3.6.1.201408250824-RELEASE
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.quicksearch.feature,3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.sts,3.6.1.201408250824-RELEASE
No repository found containing: binary,org.springsource.sts.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64,3.6.1.201408250824-RELEASE-e43
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.sts.package,3.6.1.201408250824-RELEASE-e43
No repository found containing: binary,org.springsource.sts.package_root,3.6.1.201408250824-RELEASE-e43**
```

The version I have installed is:

```
Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.6.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201407101106
Platform: Eclipse Luna (4.4)**
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 34):

The first bullet point from Martin's answer fixed my issue.  I had multiple update sites for SpringSource, including e3.7, e4.3, and e4.4.  Steps I took to fix this:

1. Select Window -> Preferences from menu
2. Expand Install/Update and select Available Software Sites
3. Uncheck update sites for SpringSource, except e4.4, and save

To test the fix:

1. Select Help -> Check for Updates

Hope this helps.  Thanks Martin for pointing this situation out.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like there is some stale data in the p2 repository cache of Eclipse/STS. I would recommend to do the following:

- make sure that you have the 4.4-based update site of STS only (among the Eclipse Luna one), but not another STS update site for a different Eclipse version.
- go to the main STS directory and delete the content of "p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache" while STS is NOT running.
- restart

This should remove the stale data and you should be able to continue with STS updates (to 3.6.1, for example).

Comment: Sorry, what if none of these steps resolve the issue? I have flushed the cache as you say, uncheck the Kepler repository from the Available Sites cause my Eclipse is 4.4 (Luna) and yet it is not working. The STS repository is only one: `http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/` and is Enabled. What should I do?

Comment: I have resolved, I had to:
`1) Export the .xml Available Software Sites to bookmarks.xml;`
2) Remove all the available software sites:
`3) Quit Eclipse;`
4) Flush the STS cache like you told in you post;
`5) Restart Eclipse;`
6) Imported the bookmarks.xml back;
`7) Removed the STS SpringSource repository;`
8) Go to Install new Software -> re-added the SpringSource repository;
`9) Installed STS 3.6.3`

Comment: hard to say what is going wrong here. Please check the list of available update sites in the preferences and make sure you have the right ones for your STS version. Please keep in mind that you shouldn't use an update site for an Eclipse version that DOES NOT match your installed Eclipse base version.

Answer (score 10):

Steps I took to fix this :

1. Close STS
2. Delete folder cache on sts-3.6.0.RELEASE\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository
3. Run STS
4. Select Window -> Preferences
5. Expand Install/Update and select Available Software Sites
6. Uncheck all update site, Except http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna and save
7. Select Help -> Check for updates
8. Select Window -> Preferences
9. Expand Install/Update and select Available Software Sites
10. Check http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/ and save
11. Select Help -> Check for updates

If u got error "STS.exe", just remove (backup first) STS.exe, and check for updates again.

Comment: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2334  "The url is for an eclipse update site. When you access it directly, you will get the 403 error, but Eclipse/STS knows how to access it properly."  - not for me...

Comment: you can do it with http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/no-repository-found-containing-error-when-update-eclipse.html, it can prevent to loss your record

Comment: Above steps worked fine for me to update sts from 3.6.3.SR1 to 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

Below is what worked for me, I'm using STS 3.7.3 Release:

First go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software sites -> Uncheck all the SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse boxes.

Then go to Help -> Check for Updates and you should now see all the updates except the one that says Spring Tool Suite. Install them if you need or ignore. Then you can follow the next steps.

From the STS download site (https://spring.io/tools/sts/all), I got the current update site link which under Update Sites: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.6/

Go to -> Help -> Install New Software -> Add this link in the Work with field and enter. Then Select All or whatever you need and Finish. It will ask to restart STS and you are done.

**Update:**
This is for version 3.8.1 in C:\Users\\Documents\New\STS at this location and when I update I didn't have any issues. If you install (unzip) STS in C directly may be then you might have this issue.

If you choose to re-install, it's better to install in Documents or if you have any other drive than C:\ to avoid such issues and spending time resolving it.

Although the question asked is for 3.6.1 I think it's for all versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and all the suggestions above didn't work for me. I stumbled on the solution by

Windows/Available Software in STS.

I noticed that the drop down on Available Software was empty and expanded the drop down to select "SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 4.5 - http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.5"

I selected all and completed the update and everything was fine after restart.